How do I debug the appengine gem?
I'm deploying a ruby on rails website to Google Cloud's app engine. I've configured the CloudSQL database (more or less) and simply want to migrate the database. Google recommends I run the following command:
bundle exec rake appengine:exec -- bundle exec rake db:migrate
Doing so gives me the following error:
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

          container = app_info["deployment"]["container"]
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Tasks: TOP => appengine:exec
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

I have no idea how to debug this. If you have any idea what I could try, please let me know! Or, if you have any information on how I can directly resolve this issue, that works too.
Thanks!
I searched recursively through the root directory of my app and found app_info in a binary file. I didn't know what to do once I saw that.
I looked at a bunch of other stack overflow threads but couldn't find anything too similar.
I made sure (to the best of my ability) that app.yaml and database.yml were structured properly.

The documentation is not as clear as one might like. Have a look through Here and Here. It seems like there is some configuration needed (however I am unfamiliar with the library so this is just a suggestion)

Did the previous comment work out for your question?

@RobertG I took a look but unfortunately I wasn't able to figure it out with the added documentation.
However, I did some ADC configuration (in the google cloud CLI) and then executed the command again. I now see:
"NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
  image = version_info["deployment"]["container"]["image"]
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Tasks: TOP => appengine:exec
(See full trace by running task with --trace)"

Thank you @engineersmnky . The information you provided me seems pertinent but I'm not sure exactly how to use it. Gets me closer to the goal though!

@GarrettMoore, try checking this documentation on debugging an instance. This issue is more on the Ruby side, I would suggest deploying a sample Ruby code first just like the previous comment as we don't have enough context with regards to your error. Or if you could post a sample code that could be replicated, that would be awesome!

I has same issue and fixed it by writing this in Gemfile:
gem 'google-serverless-exec', github: "masuidrive/serverless-exec-ruby", branch: "update-to-latest-gcloud"
gem "appengine", "~> 0.7.0"

I also sent a pull request to the repo:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/serverless-exec-ruby/pull/28
